# How to lighten text based on background in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to add a textual tattoo to an image in Illustrator, and would like the lighten the text based on the skin color in the image as shown in the image below from a Photoshop tutorial to account for the way the tattoo reflects the light. Is there a way to do something similar in Illustrator?

[image]

Comment: Questions should be self-contained & not reliant on external resources demanding the user clicks away from this site.

Comment: While it's possible to create some pseudo lighting... it's not a straightforward thing in Illustrator. One would probably need to use gradient meshes and clipping masks. The gist of it -- make some areas lighter and others darker — is possible in Illustrator. However, detailing such a thing is *highly* dependent upon the artwork and the lighting of the desired photo. (And if the base is a photo, I'm uncertain Illustrator is warranted for the composite image.)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I wouldn't use illustrator for this to be honest.  It would be better to do it in Photoshop or some other raster image editor.  If your text/tattoo design has been made in Illustrator, you could import the AI file into Photoshop.  Is there some reason you want to do this all inside Illustrator?